# How long does installing Linux Mint take?

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

I install Linux besides Windows XP. Now I clicked `yes` on something the installation-thing said takes long time.

How long does it take before it gets further?

Information on my hardware: 
Quadcore ~2.5 ghz
8 gb Ram (i dont know which kind tho, or what Hz)
500gb HDD

Further the waiting doesn't make the PC sluggish, you can work on the PC (with working i mean looking for help on google haha)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It took about 10 minutes, for anyone who wonders about the same. I guess with smaller partitions it will be quicker.

Comment: Cool. You might also improve your question adding some details about your hardware to make your question valuable.

Comment: @tomas i hope that is good now. say if otherwise :)

Comment: Well... Not for everyone.